# Finding heat of formation

Tags: thermodynamics

The heats of combustion of $\ce{C_xH_y}$, $\ce{C}$, and $\ce{H2}$ are $a, b,\text{and } c$ cal respectively. The heat of formation of $\ce{C_xH_y}$ will be:

The answer is
$-\left(x b+\frac{y c}{2}-a\right)$ cal

But I am getting negative of it by adding equations:
$$\ce{C_xH_y} + (x+\frac{y}{4})\ce{O2->}x\ce{CO2}+\frac{y}{2}\ce{H2O} \text{ , }\Delta H=a \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$\ce{C} + \ce{O2->}\ce{CO2}\text{ , }\Delta H=b \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$\ce{H_2} + \frac{1}{2}\ce{O2->}\ce{H2O} \text{ , }\Delta H=c \tag{3}\label{3}$$

$\Delta H_f=-1\times\eqref{1}+x\times\eqref{2}+\frac{y}{2}\times\eqref{3}=-a+bx+\frac{cy}{2}$

Comment: What are your x and y?

Comment: The same x and y which is in question

Comment: Using photos of text instead of text itself is strongly discouraged for multiple reasons. 3 main reasons are  1/  Impossible to search for it 2/ Impossible to be reused in answers 3/ Laziness of writing puts extra burden on shoulders of responders while reading and evaluating it.

Comment: Be aware combustion and formation heat have switched products and reactants when the value is evaluated from component contributions.

Comment: All should be in units like cal/mol or cal/kg, not just cal.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong excep for not applying correct sign. All values of $a,b,c$ should be negative values because for each equation, heat gives away. It seems, the values given in question is just the numerical value without a sign. Asker expects you to apply correct sign when you do your calculations. Fault is on who wrote the question.

Comment: it seems to me your assessment is correct, and the given answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> **The question:** The heats of combustion of $\ce{C_xH_y}$, $\ce{C}$, and $\ce{H2}$ are $a, b,$ and $c$ $\pu{cal mol-1}$, respectively. What will be the heat of formation of $\ce{C_xH_y}$?

We have three combustion reactions to consider:

$$\ce{C + O2 -> CO2} \quad \Delta H_{\mathrm{comp}(\ce{CO2})} = b \tag{1}$$
$$\ce{H2 + 1/2 O2 -> H2O}  \quad \Delta H_{\mathrm{comp}(\ce{H2})} = c \tag{2}$$
$$\ce{C_xH_y + ($x$ +y/4) O2 -> x CO2 + y/2 H2O}  \quad \Delta H_{\mathrm{comp}(\ce{C_xH_y})} = a \tag{3}$$

Assuming the given answer is correct, I have to tell this straight: The wrong doing in this question is giving all three heat of combustion values as their numerical values and not mentioning it in the question (thus, solver has to assume it). That, I called being tricky at this level of education. For example, if the question is a multiple choice, then it may include both $-\left(x b+\frac{y c}{2}-a\right) \ \pu{cal mol-1}$ and $+\left(x b+\frac{y c}{2}-a\right) \ \pu{cal mol-1}$ as chices to pick as an answer. Too bad for students.

Let's assume $\Delta H_{\mathrm{comp}(\ce{CO2})}$ is $-b$ in the equation $(1)$, and so on. Now we can rewrite above equations as:

$$\ce{C + O2 -> CO2} \quad \Delta H_{\mathrm{comp}(\ce{CO2})} = -b \tag{4}$$
$$\ce{H2 + 1/2 O2 -> H2O}  \quad \Delta H_{\mathrm{comp}(\ce{H2})} = -c \tag{5}$$
$$\ce{C_xH_y + ($x$ +y/4) O2 -> x CO2 + y/2 H2O}  \quad \Delta H_{\mathrm{comp}(\ce{C_xH_y})} = -a \tag{6}$$

From the equation $(4)$:

$$\Delta H_{\mathrm{comp}(\ce{CO2})} = \Delta H_{f(\ce{CO2})} - \left(\Delta H_{f(\ce{C})}  + \Delta H_{f(\ce{O2})}  \right) = \Delta H_{f(\ce{CO2})} - \left(0  + 0  \right) = -b\\ \therefore \ \Delta H_{f(\ce{CO2})}  = -b \tag7$$

Simillarly, from the equation $(5)$:

$$\ \Delta H_{f(\ce{H2O})}  = -c, \tag8$$

and from the equation $(6)$ :

$$\Delta H_{\mathrm{comp}(\ce{C_xH_y})} = \left(x\Delta H_{f(\ce{CO2})}  + \frac{y}{2}\Delta H_{f(\ce{H2O})}  \right) - \Delta H_{f(\ce{C_xH_y})} = \left(-xb - \frac{yc}{2}\right) - \Delta H_{f(\ce{C_xH_y})} = -a$$

$$\ \Delta H_{f(\ce{C_xH_y})}  = +a - \left(xb + \frac{yc}{2}\right) \tag9$$

The equation $(9)$ is the correct answer.